# How can I remove only density from antd design pro table toolbar?

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

```
  <ProTable
  search={false}
  dateFormatter="string"
  cardBordered
  tooltip={false}
  
  {...props}

  size="large"
></ProTable>
```

I want to only remove density not refresh or settings. I even asked the question in ChatGPT but it had not answer :)

Comment: Off-topic here: I just checked the *tag* for `ant-design-pro` there is no description and very little popularity over here, maybe you can find a design-specific forum more helpful? Anyways back on topic: what is `density` in the question that you are talking about? Is there a React error? Can you provide more code/info regarding the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `options` prop of ProTable to hide the reload button.

```
<ProTable
  search={false}
  dateFormatter="string"
  cardBordered
  tooltip={false}
  
  {...props}

  size="large"
  options={{
    reload: false,
  }}
></ProTable>
```

To read more, click [here](https://procomponents.ant.design/en-US/components/table).